# Limit the nodes in a linked list

Tags: python, linked-list, queue, heap

Is it possible to limit the nodes kept in a linked list?

For simplicity, take the example below:

```
import numpy as np

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self,data,prev):
        self.data = data
        self.prev = prev

myData_prev = None

for x in range(10):
    data = np.random.random((3,2))
    myData = LinkedList(data,myData_prev)

    myData_prev = myData

print(myData.data)
print(myData.prev.data)
print(myData.prev.prev.data)
print(myData.prev.prev.prev.data)  ## DELETED OR NO LONGER AVAILABLE
```

Pretend the 'data' is quite large or the range is indefinite.  Is it possible to limit the nodes kept in memory?  For simplicity, say I only need the latest 3 nodes or 30%.

I guess I have 2 questions. First, how can the above question be done, maintaining the linked list approach.  Second, is there a better approach not using a linked list.  I guess I could use a queue/deque or heapq with a limit, but it'll be kind of harder to get the data in relation to the other, right?

Comment: Your question is not clear: if you want to restrict the *number of nodes* in a list - of course you can do it, it's up to you how you want to implement it: if it's "full" you can either ignore a request to "add" a new node, drop the oldest one, etc. If you want to control what's in-memory and what not then AFAIK it's not doable in Python, but even if it would - it doesn't make any sense. If you want to work on lower-level - use lower level languages. Do you have a *real* reason to come up with such a requirement?

Comment: did you benchmark your application, measured the memory in-use and found that *this* is a bottleneck?

Comment: Linked List isn't a great data structure for this.  It's doable, but you're probably looking for a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

Comment: how do i 'drop' the oldest ones from the linked list?  I didnt benchmark but i can see the memory being used go up to 4GB when running the program. Its for a programming game where I am trying to implement machine learning.  There's no need to keep the very old input data that were many many turns ago thats why I would like to limit the nodes being kept.  Its not necessary, it still works, just wondering if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Node({}, {})'.format(self.data, self.next)

class LinkedList:      
    def __init__(self, iterable=(), maxlen=3):
        self.head = None
        self.length = 0
        if maxlen < 2:
            raise ValueError
        self.maxlen = maxlen
        for item in iterable:
            self.add(item)
    def add(self, data):
        self._check_and_remove_last()
        self.head = Node(data, self.head)
        self.length += 1
    def _check_and_remove_last(self):
        if self.length < self.maxlen:
            return
        new_tail = self.head
        while new_tail.next.next:
            new_tail = new_tail.next
        # new_tail.next is now the last Node in the Linked List
        new_tail.next = None
        self.length -= 1
```

Removing the last element of the linked list means you either have to keep track of the second-to-last node in the linked list (not a very natural thing to do), or traverse the whole linked list every time. You can get around this by using a doubly linked list and doing something like `self.tail.prev.next = None`, or just using the built in [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which makes all this a breeze

Comment: ok thanks for showing me a possible implementation.  But yea I guess linked list is not really the way to go for this scenario.  Thanks again